# Can you determine rotation/camera calibration from series of images separated by pure rotation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have a series of about 50 images, each separated by a small rotation and taken from the same camera. The images are feature-dense, and I can calculate a homography from image-to-image easily.

My question is, is there any way to determine the rotation matrix and/or intrinsic camera calibration parameters given just these images?

Answer (score 2):

If the images are related by pure rotation, then the homography would give you the rotation matrix.  If the rotation is in-plane, then you would not be able to compute the intrinsics.

Comment: Yeah, I was just doing the math and got that for a pure rotation, the homography would be equal to KRK^-1. So that solves that problem. What do you mean when you say the rotation is "in-plane"?

Comment: In-plane means rotation about the camera's optical axis, aka roll. Out-of-plane rotation involved pitch and yaw.

Comment: Ah, got it. All of the rotation is pitch and yaw. Can you give any suggestion how I would got about determining the intrinsic parameters?